# How to remove .htaccess virus?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, virus

First time posting so bear with me please!

My friend's site has been hacked and the .htaccess file (which I really know nothing about) has been injected with a malicious redirect that forces search engines to the see the site as a "harmful website." If you look at the .htaccess file you can see it's Russian or at least ends in `.ru`. Seeing as I know very little about this stuff, I simply tried to restore the good .htaccess file back with his host. This doesn't work as the virus just recreates the infected .htaccess file.

When I searched through the rest of his directories, I can see the same bad .htaccess file in most of the folders.

I can't seem to help him get rid of this virus.

Answer (score 2):

1. change the `root` password
2. make sure that `root` is the owner of `.htaccess` (that's the default!)
3. remove write permissions!

Comment: When you say "root" do you mean the root directory? I mean, we have tried to change all the passwords ranging from his administrator password, ftp, and database password. Even after doing all this, the .htaccess file recreates itself. When you say make sure he's owner of the .htaccess file, where do you find that? I know how to remove permissions at least.

Comment: no, I mean `root` user on the machine. Not the Joomla's administrator.

Comment: Oh ok, we have also changed his user name on his hosting account. All username and passwords (that we have access to) have been changed.

Comment: It wasn't his hosting account that was tampered, it was the server (some kind of Linux, right?). I would also suggest going over Joomla security-checklist: http://docs.joomla.org/Category:Security_Checklist